# How do we stop the app from making a reset for the user data when the user moves to a different page?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, state-management

I made an app for remindering the user to drink water, and on the home page, I provide a counter when the user clicks on it will counts the amount of water and then, add it to today's records. And my problem is when I navigate to the profile page and back to the home page both the counter and today's records will reset and I don't want that to happen instead of that I want to keep them as they are, and the same thing happen in the profile page.I'm new to Flutter and I don't know how to solve this problem. If anyone can help me I'll appreciate it.

This is the home page file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:water_reminder_app/widgets/responsive_container.dart';
import '../widgets/drink_record.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final double weight;
  final String unit;
  final String bedTime;
  final String wakeUpTime;
  Home({
    required this.weight,
    required this.unit,
    required this.bedTime,
    required this.wakeUpTime,
  });

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  // static const _amountAdded = 'amount';
  // static const _recomendedWaterAmount = 'recommendedAmount';
  // static const _item = 'recordItem';

  late ValueNotifier<List<DrinkRecordModel>> _items;
  double amount = 0;
  late double recommendedAmount;

  String _calculateRecommendedAmount() {
    if (widget.unit == 'kilograms') {
      double kiloResult = widget.weight * 30;
      return kiloResult.round().toString();
    } else {
      double pounResult = widget.weight * 0.5;
      return pounResult.round().toString();
    }
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _saveData();
    // _getData();
    amount;
    // recommendedAmount = _calculateRecommendedAmount();
    _items = ValueNotifier([
      DrinkRecordModel(
        time: '11:00 AM',
        amountOfWater: '${widget.unit == 'kilograms' ? '175 ml' : '6 fl oz'}',
      ),
    ]);
  }

  // void _saveData() async {
  //   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //   prefs.setDouble(_amountAdded, amount);
  //   prefs.setDouble(_recomendedWaterAmount, recommendedAmount);
  //   prefs.setStringList(_item, _items as List<String>);
  // }

  // void _getData() async {
  //   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //   prefs.getDouble(_amountAdded) ?? amount;
  //   prefs.getDouble(_recomendedWaterAmount) ?? recommendedAmount;
  //   prefs.getStringList(_item) ?? _items;
  // }

  String changeUnit() {
    return widget.unit == 'kilograms' ? '175 ml' : '6 fl oz';
  }

  void _deleteItem(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _items.value.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

  void _editItem(int index) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        String updatedTime = _items.value[index].time;
        String updatedAmount = _items.value[index].amountOfWater;
        TextEditingController timeController =
            TextEditingController(text: updatedTime);
        TextEditingController amountController =
            TextEditingController(text: updatedAmount);
        return Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
              return Container(
                height: 300,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Edit Record',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 7, 107, 132),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Time',
                        hintText: 'Enter new time',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          updatedTime = value;
                          _items.value[index].time = value;
                        });
                      },
                      controller: timeController,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Amount of Water',
                        hintText: 'Enter new amount',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          updatedAmount = value;
                          _items.value[index].amountOfWater = value;
                        });
                      },
                      controller: amountController,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
                        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 7, 107, 132),
                      ),
                      child: Text('Save'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _items.notifyListeners();
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Home;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(top: 120, left: 33, right: 33, bottom: 5),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 295,
                height: 238,
                child: Card(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 200, 250, 0.415),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 46, bottom: 21, left: 62, right: 62),
                        child: Text(
                          'Your Drink Goal',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            bottom: 21, left: 52, right: 52),
                        child: Text(
                          '${amount.round()} / ${_calculateRecommendedAmount()} ${widget.unit == 'kilograms' ? 'ml' : 'oz'}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      //coffee ListTile button
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            bottom: 20, left: 57, right: 57),
                        child: ResponsiveContainer(
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              // '${widget.unit == 'kilograms' ? '175 ml' : '6 fl oz'}',
                              changeUnit(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 17,
                              ),
                            ),
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.coffee_sharp,
                              size: 70,
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                widget.unit == 'kilograms'
                                    ? amount += 175
                                    : amount += 6;
                                _items.value.add(DrinkRecordModel(
                                  time: TimeOfDay.now().format(context),
                                  amountOfWater: changeUnit(),
                                ));
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 173, right: 173),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_upward,
                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 7, 107, 132),
              ),
            ),
            ResponsiveContainer(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 10, right: 10),
                child: Text(
                  'Click here to confirm that you drank water',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(146, 0, 0, 0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 15,
                bottom: 5,
                left: 15,
              ),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "Today's records",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 15),
              child: ResponsiveContainer(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 155,
                  width: 350,
                  //today's records card
                  child: Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 220, 239, 249),
                    shadowColor: const Color.fromARGB(14, 0, 0, 0),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    ),
                    child: ValueListenableBuilder<List<DrinkRecordModel>>(
                      valueListenable: _items,
                      builder: (context, items, child) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                          itemCount: items.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return DrinkRecord(
                              time: items[index].time,
                              amountOfWater: items[index].amountOfWater,
                              onDelete: () {
                                _deleteItem(index);
                              },
                              onEdit: () {
                                _editItem(index);
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can find the rest of the project on this GitHub link [text](https://github.com/ftoome545/Water-Reminder-app/tree/main)
In this link I provide a video to show you my problem [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ib1XTOWyajo)

I tried to use SharedPreferences but it doesn't work for me as I said I'm new in Flutter maybe I didn't do it the right way.

Comment: You need to use a `provider` to save the state of the `amount` value across all your app screens. You should also use `sharedpreferences` to save that data for when the user closes the app. To use it properly you need to get the value from your sharedpreferences in your `initstate`, and update it when user clicks the counter

Comment: thank you, I did what you said and it work with me now.